# Queue (Colas) no trabajan en PHP

Tags: php, laravel, curl, queue

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en PHP, la cual tiene una función de **descarga** que consiste en obtener data de un sitio web externo y guardar dicha data en mi base de datos MySQL.

Dado que la descarga de toda esta información tarda considerablemente **(30-40 minutos aprox)** me encontré con el problema de que no se puede realizar otra acción en el sistema mientras dure este proceso de descarga. Si otro usuario al mismo tiempo quiere acceder a otras vistas o probar otras funcionalidades la página se queda cargando hasta que termina de procesar la solicitud (osea hasta que se completa toda la descarga) generando un problema, ya que para que puedan hacer otra operación con la aplicación deben esperar que termine esta descarga.

Investigando sobre el tema, me encontré con una posible solución: Usar **queue** la cual es como una cola que se ejecuta asíncronamente permitiendo hacer esas descargas por separado.

Este es el botón que sirve para descargar:

```
<button id="btn_descargaOrdenes" class="btn btn-outline-dark">
                    Descarga masiva
                </button>
```

Esta es mi función Javascript:

```js
$('#btn_descargaOrdenes').click(() => {
    swal.fire({
        title: 'Está a punto de descargar masivamente.',
        text: "Este proceso puede tomar varios minutos. ¿Está seguro?",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Sí. Continuar'
    }).then((result) => {
        if(result.value){
            $('#btn_descargaOrdenes').attr("disabled", true);
            try{
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/ordenes',
                    headers: { "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token },
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response){
                            console.log(response);
                            alert("Descarga de órdenes de compra finalizada");
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }catch(ex){
                console.log(ex);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

En mi controlador **OrdenesCompraController** tengo la siguiente función que se encarga de recibir la petición ajax

```js
public function store(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()) {
            dispatch(new DescargarOrdenesCompra());
        }
    }
```

Esta función dirige a mi job: **DescargarOrdenesCompra**, donde tengo un erro porque al parecer no está procesando el método **handle**:

```js
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Http\Controllers\OrdenesCompraController;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class DescargarOrdenesCompra implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $ordenesCompra;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(){
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(OrdenesCompraController $ordenes){
        $ordenes->descargarProformas();
    }
}
```

Y debería direccionar a mi método de descarga ubicado en **OrdenesCompraController** donde se ejecutaría mi algoritmo de descarga donde aplico Curl y almaceno en BD. Esto funciona exitosamente pero ahora debo hacerlo por separado. Agradezco una posible solución.

```js
public function descargarProformas(){
        //ALGORITMO DE SCRAPING E INSERCIÓN EN BD YA PROBADO EXITOSAMENTE
}
```

Comment: Tienes corriendo `php artisan queue:work`?

Comment: Creo que no. Utilicé el artisan para crear los jobs, no apliqué ese comando.

Comment: Creería que tienen que tener corriendo ese comondo para que los jobs se procesen.  "Laravel incluye un trabajador de cola que procesará nuevos trabajos a medida que se empujan a la cola.". Revisa la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker) y mira si es un job lo que sirve para lo que quieres hacer, y cómo implementarlo.